# Elasticsearch 2.0.0 cluster zen discovery in docker

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, google-compute-engine, elasticsearch-2.0

I tried to run the elasticsearch cluster on 2 different nodes of google compute engine in docker way.

With 1.7.1, the unicast works, but **with 2.0.0, it didn't work, 2 nodes can not join together**.

Below is the `Dockerfile`, `run command` and `elasticsearch.yml`. thanks

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM java:8

#ENV ES_PKG_NAME elasticsearch-2.0.0
ENV ES_PKG_NAME elasticsearch-1.7.1

RUN \
  cd / && \
  #wget https://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/release/org/elasticsearch/distribution/tar/elasticsearch/2.0.0/$ES_PKG_NAME.tar.gz && \
  wget https://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/$ES_PKG_NAME.tar.gz && \
  tar xvzf $ES_PKG_NAME.tar.gz && \
  rm -f $ES_PKG_NAME.tar.gz && \
  mv /$ES_PKG_NAME /elasticsearch

RUN mkdir -p /data/mnt
RUN chmod 777 -R /data/mnt
RUN chmod 777 -R /elasticsearch

RUN useradd -m docker && echo "docker:docker" | chpasswd && adduser docker sudo
USER docker

EXPOSE 9200
EXPOSE 9300

ADD elasticsearch.yml /elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml

ENTRYPOINT ["/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch"]
```

**run command**

```
docker run -it -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 \
    -v /data/elasticsearch:/data/mnt \
    -e ES_HEAP_SIZE=4g \
    --restart=always --name elastic_search \
    elastic_search \
    --node.name=$(hostname) \
    --network.publish_host=$(hostname -i) \
    --discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled=false \
    --discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=10.240.0.58:9300,10.240.0.59:9300
```

**elasticsearch.yml**

```
cluster.name: hello

# path
path.conf: /elasticsearch/config
path.data: /data/mnt/data
path.logs: /data/mnt/log
path.plugins: /elasticsearch/plugins
path.work: /data/mnt/work

# index option
index.number_of_shards: 5
index.number_of_replicas: 2
```

**console of node-a**

```
[2015-11-02 04:09:59,133][INFO ][node                     ] [elastic-a.c.ikalacomputeenginetest.internal] version[2.0.0], pid[1], build[de54438/2015-10-22T08:09:48Z]
[2015-11-02 04:09:59,134][INFO ][node                     ] [elastic-a.c.ikalacomputeenginetest.internal] initializing ...
[2015-11-02 04:09:59,488][INFO ][plugins                  ] [elastic-a.c.ikalacomputeenginetest.internal] loaded [license], sites [hq, kopf]
[2015-11-02 04:09:59,523][INFO ][env                      ] [elastic-a.c.ikalacomputeenginetest.internal] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/data/mnt (/dev/sda9)]], net usable_space [4.5gb], net total_space [6.4gb], spins? [possibly], types [ext4]
[2015-11-02 04:10:01,577][INFO ][node                     ] [elastic-a.c.ikalacomputeenginetest.internal] initialized
[2015-11-02 04:10:01,577][INFO ][node                     ] [elastic-a.c.ikalacomputeenginetest.internal] starting ...
[2015-11-02 04:10:01,667][INFO ][transport                ] [elastic-a.c.ikalacomputeenginetest.internal] publish_address {10.240.0.58:9300}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9300}, {[::1]:9300}
[2015-11-02 04:10:01,693][INFO ][discovery                ] [elastic-a.c.ikalacomputeenginetest.internal] hello/NULtHr65Sm-1d47NfJ_uhQ
[2015-11-02 04:10:04,732][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [elastic-a.c.ikalacomputeenginetest.internal] new_master {elastic-a.c.ikalacomputeenginetest.internal}{NULtHr65Sm-1d47NfJ_uhQ}{10.240.0.58}{10.240.0.58:9300}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
[2015-11-02 04:10:04,812][INFO ][http                     ] [elastic-a.c.ikalacomputeenginetest.internal] publish_address {10.240.0.58:9200}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9200}, {[::1]:9200}
[2015-11-02 04:10:04,813][INFO ][node                     ] [elastic-a.c.ikalacomputeenginetest.internal] started
[2015-11-02 04:10:04,904][INFO ][license.plugin.core      ] [elastic-a.c.ikalacomputeenginetest.internal] license [b61278f5-5cc8-40b0-87cd-820f1b8d5c58] - valid
```

**console of node-b**

```
[2015-11-02 04:11:34,619][INFO ][node                     ] [elastic-b.c.ikalacomputeenginetest.internal] version[2.0.0], pid[1], build[de54438/2015-10-22T08:09:48Z]
[2015-11-02 04:11:34,620][INFO ][node                     ] [elastic-b.c.ikalacomputeenginetest.internal] initializing ...
[2015-11-02 04:11:34,866][INFO ][plugins                  ] [elastic-b.c.ikalacomputeenginetest.internal] loaded [license], sites [hq, kopf]
[2015-11-02 04:11:34,896][INFO ][env                      ] [elastic-b.c.ikalacomputeenginetest.internal] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/data/mnt (/dev/sda9)]], net usable_space [4.7gb], net total_space [6.4gb], spins? [possibly], types [ext4]
[2015-11-02 04:11:37,007][INFO ][node                     ] [elastic-b.c.ikalacomputeenginetest.internal] initialized
[2015-11-02 04:11:37,008][INFO ][node                     ] [elastic-b.c.ikalacomputeenginetest.internal] starting ...
[2015-11-02 04:11:37,085][INFO ][transport                ] [elastic-b.c.ikalacomputeenginetest.internal] publish_address {10.240.0.59:9300}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9300}, {[::1]:9300}
[2015-11-02 04:11:37,108][INFO ][discovery                ] [elastic-b.c.ikalacomputeenginetest.internal] hello/DD6mqmC4SC2K3RXx4Dy8xg
[2015-11-02 04:11:40,134][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [elastic-b.c.ikalacomputeenginetest.internal] new_master {elastic-b.c.ikalacomputeenginetest.internal}{DD6mqmC4SC2K3RXx4Dy8xg}{10.240.0.59}{10.240.0.59:9300}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
[2015-11-02 04:11:40,199][INFO ][http                     ] [elastic-b.c.ikalacomputeenginetest.internal] publish_address {10.240.0.59:9200}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9200}, {[::1]:9200}
[2015-11-02 04:11:40,200][INFO ][node                     ] [elastic-b.c.ikalacomputeenginetest.internal] started
[2015-11-02 04:11:40,281][INFO ][license.plugin.core      ] [elastic-b.c.ikalacomputeenginetest.internal] license [16216eed-f88a-4c59-8578-b1cba069a219] - valid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just ran into the exact same problem : when launching your docker container, you have to change the variable **--network.publish_host**, as it is now in ES 2.0 **network.host** : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html#settings.

This should do the trick !

Comment: Hi Louis

This didn't work, from doc (The `network.host` setting is a simple setting to automatically set both `network.bind_host` and `network.publish_host` to the same host value.)  

If I set `bind_host` to the internal ip, will cause BindTransportException error

Comment: OK sorry for that Browny. Did you try launching your elastic containers with the --net=host config parameter ?

Comment: @louis thank you so much, just wondering how did this work. the --net=host definitely works. But if I manually create a network using "docker network create <network>", then I do --net=<network> to this new network that's created, it wouldn't auto detect and join as cluster.